# Why doesn't SQL server delete redumentary indexex as opposed to updating them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I create a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(TestId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
FName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
LName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_TestID PRIMARY KEY(TestId))
```

SQL Server creates related to Primary key, one in `sys.key_constraints` and one in `sys.indexes`. As can be seen from running the queries below, before and after the creation of table.

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
    sys.key_constraints

SELECT Count(*)
FROM
    sys.indexes
WHERE
    object_id IN (SELECT object_id
                  FROM
                      sys.objects
                  WHERE
                      type_desc = 'USER_TABLE')
```

It also uses them.

When I ran this

```
INSERT INTO test
VALUES
    ('Me', 'You')
```

The execution plan shows `Clustered Index Insert`.

But when I drop the constraint

```
ALTER TABLE Test
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_TestID
GO
```

and then ran the queries 2 queries above, the `sys.key_constraints` has 1 less count then what it has, which if exactly what it's supposed to be. But `sys.indexes` still has the same count, though when I run this

```
SELECT *
FROM
    sys.indexes
WHERE
    object_id IN (SELECT object_id
                  FROM
                      sys.objects
                  WHERE
                      type_desc = 'USER_TABLE')
    AND
    object_id = object_id(N'Test')
ORDER BY
    [name]
```

The `name` is set to `NULL` and `index_id` to 0. But why not just delete this like we did with that row in `sys.key_constraint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary key constraint happens to be enforced by the clustered index. when you drop the constraint you also drop the clustered index, leaving a [heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188270%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in place. The heap has its own entry in [`sys.indexes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx):

> Type of index:
>   **0 = Heap**
>   1 = Clustered
>   2 = Nonclustered